# Getting JSON from a website with no visible files using p5.js

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

I am trying to import a json file from a website using p5.js, and i thought it would be quite easy, however when i tried it i realized the json was actually just in plain text on the page (It is the only thing on the page). I checked chrome web tools to look at index.html, but i was greeted by "(index)", is it a problem with google or am i just going to have to use something else than this?

```
function preload() {
  httpGet('leaderboard.popcat.click', 'json', function(response) {
    
  });
}
//there are the setup and draw functions aswell
```

I got an error when i ran the code aswell, it was
Error: JSONP request to url failed

[here is a picture of the page btw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTTHX.png), (the url is leaderboard.popcat.click)

EDIT: The main problem i am having is that there is no file in https://leaderboard.popcat.click/, not the getting of json.
The network tab says no such url exists, and i believe that is because of the fact that i didn't specify a file.
[Here is the console output aswell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtmjF.png)

Comment: JSONP is not the same as JSON and has difference semantics. As to what the actual issue is, if it's not related to an incorrect jsonp thing, would need to have additional info, like console/network tab output etc.

Comment: Yes, I would say that you need to look at the network tab in the Chrome devtools to be able to see what the actual end point URL is that you're trying to access.

Comment: Note the 404 and the URL in the console output: https://editor.p5js.org//leaderboard.popcat.click while what I think you want is http://leaderboard.popcat.click maybe all you need to do is use the full url instead of a relative url, however, you may get a cross-site-scripting error..

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by starting chrome in no-cors mode or whatever it's called AND using the full path of the website. I got it into no-cors mode by making a shortcut with this link

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security  --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp"
```

and running it as an administrator